# The best way to share all records of an object using an ownership based sharing rule

Tags: sharing-rule

To share all records of an object, I've always used `sharing rules` from public group - all internal users to group/role/etc

Just discovered that this approach does not share records owned by Queues.

I could do a `criteria based rule` like recordId starts aX6, but am I missing something?  Since you get more owner based rules than criteria based rules per object, seems better to do it using an owner based rule - but how?

I could add the user to the queue, but I really just want a sharing rule that will share all records of this object, period.

Comment: wait what really? I'll need to raise this.

Comment: Just wondering if all records need to be shared why dont you change OWD, please do share scenario as well ( it sounds interesting) 
Also if that object has queue in the dropdown you'd also get Owned by "Queue" option.

Comment: Considering there are more ownership based rules than criteria, making multiple rules based on queue and internal user should resolve the issue

Comment: @elijah There are cases where a small group of users should be able to view or edit all records of an object, and i assumed all internal users would do the trick.  Creating a rule for each queue requires remembering to do that if a new queue is added.  I would go with the criteria-based hack as its more resilient.

Comment: In that case why not provide modify all on that object to certain set of users via permission set and write addError in apex to avoid accidental deletion of records.

Comment: i may be able to give modify all and use a muting permission set to remove delete. the criteria based rule still seems preferable as i'm really hestitant to go with muting permission sets other than when dealing w managed packages, though this seems like a possibly useful case.